# How to evaluate $n \choose k$ for $n\lt0$

Tags: combinatorics

> **How do I compute $\displaystyle{-2 \choose 4}$?**

I can't find the solution to this. I didn't know you were allowed a negative number as $n$.

Comment: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html).

Comment: $\Large 5.\mbox{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large{-2 \choose 4}}&
={-\bracks{-2} + 4 - 1 \choose 4}\pars{-1}^{4}={5 \choose 4}=\color{#66f}{\large 5}
\end{align}

> See [formula $\pars{5}$ in this site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) .

Answer (score 3):

One usually defines $\alpha \choose k$ for $\alpha$ real as
$${ \alpha \choose k } = \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1) \cdots (\alpha-k+1)}{k!}$$

Comment: That applies to $\alpha$ nonnegative only. It needs to be analytically continued to negative $\alpha$.

Comment: MathNoob: You are mistaking $\alpha$ for $k$.